# Solving quadratic functions in Python

Tags: python

I'm having  a problem modifying the code so function *solve_quadratic*, that returns both solutions of a generic quadratic as a pair (2-tuple) when the coefficients are given as parameters. It should work like this:

[image]

This is my code

```
import math

def solve_quadratic(a, b, c):


    d = int(b*b) - int(4*a*c)

    sol1 = (-b-math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
    sol2 = (-b+math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
    print('({} {})'.format(sol2, sol1))

    return solve_quadratic



def main():

    solve_quadratic(1, -3, 2)
    solve_quadratic(1, 2, 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Welcome to code-review. Your questions currently reads as though the code isn't working. If this is the case, then this question is off-topic, as we can only review complete and working code here. If I have mis-understood, than you might consider rephrasing the question.

Comment: @VisualMelon  the code works just fine, it basically serves the purpose of the quadratic formula . I want to modify it as mentioned above so that the function solve_quadratic returns the two solutions into the main function . by two solutions I mean the (2,0, 1,0) and (-1,0,-1,0)

Comment: If your code isn't producing the expected output, then it isn't working fine: requests to change or fix basic functionality are not on-topic on code-review. It might have been better to ask this question on stack overflow, but you'd have to check their [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: @VisualMelon: let's not get pedantic here: the code merely needs to swap the `print()` for a `return` statement. Also, strip the unnecessary `int()` calls. Essentially the code nearly works (new users often confuse printing a result with returning it), and can be fixed in 30 seconds flat, far less than time arguing about it.

Comment: @smci while I agree the fixes are minor, our basic standards require the OP understand the code and that the code works correctly. While beginner questions are welcome here, and stuff like the `int` might be considered an 'edge case' they missed, the fact that they are explicitly asking for help with changing the basic functionality means it must be off-topic (in my opinion). Remember that putting a question on hold is an opportunity for the OP to discuss with us why it is on hold and resolve it: we want to ensure that every question is high quality.

Comment: Ed1995: all you need to do to get this reopened is edit the code to work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

1. **Obvious bug: confusing `print` with `return` in a function**

   - your spec says modify the code so your function **returns** both solutions as a tuple. Not **print** them, which is what it currently does.
   - remove the `print(...)` line inside the function
   - the line `return solve_quadratic` should now be `return sol1, sol2`
   - in general get out of the bad habit of having functions print their result instead of returning it (strictly that makes it only a subroutine, not a function). Returning the result is much more flexible, we can use it in unit-test, send it into another function or iterator, etc. If you only want to print the function's output, have your calling code do that: `print(solve_quadratic(...))`. So you lose nothing and gain a huge amount by having functions always return their result.
2. Nastier bug: Your code is **arbitrarily rounding subvalues to integers for no good reason, and hence returns the wrong answer for many non-integer inputs**:

   - Why does it do `d = int(b*b) - int(4*a*c)`, that's weird and outright wrong. Why not simply `d = b*b - 4*a*c`? Why are you rounding anything before the division? (If your intent is merely to get rounded solutions, then do say `round(sol, 1)` at the end)
   - Example: calling your function on `a=1, b=4, c=4.1` will wrongly round the slightly negative discriminant up to 0 and wrongly return a real result, where it should throw a ValueError
   - the code is not quite requiring all of `a,b,c` to be integers, but nearly: it (totally arbitrarily) requires b to at least be the sqrt of an integer, and `4*a*c` to be an integer.
   - as an aside we've uncovered that your spec/teacher didn't seem to care about testing with non-integer inputs.
   - (at least in Python 3 you no longer have to care about integer division and unwanted rounding when dividing an integer numerator by an integer denominator, which would have given a second unwanted source of rounding on the line `(-b + math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)`)
3. **Exception for negative discriminant case, do you need to handle it**

   - You don't handle the case where the discriminant is negative `d = int(b*b) - int(4*a*c)` hence taking `sqrt(d)` will blow up (if you're looking for real roots only). If you want to handle that, you could `try...catch` the `ValueError: math domain error` and return the tuple `None, None`. Probably this doesn't matter in your exercise, but it's good practice not to write exception-happy code that generally behaves well (unless you explicitly want the `ValueError` on negative discriminant). It all depends on what behavior your client code expects.
4. **You can do `from math import sqrt` for common everyday identifiers**

   - Now you can write `sqrt` rather than `math.sqrt` and your code is shorter and clearer. Python ain't Java :) We don't want to see fully qualified package names for simple everyday stuff like `sqrt`, `abs`, `ceil`, `random` etc. Well maybe some teachers do, but they were probably indoctrinated in Java-land, with abominations like `System.out.println()` and `.toString()`, and simple lines exceed 80 chars and thus are unreadable (and in fact defeat some diff'ing tools). Those teachers are made of wood, therefore weigh the same as a duck, therefore...
   - Just don't abuse with huge import lines: `from package import thing1, thing2, thing3, thing4, thing5...`. Do `import sqrt` if you want to use lots of its functions. You can still also do `from math import sqrt, abs` for the subset of functions you use a lot. Yes, this is strictly frowned upon, but it makes for shorter clearer code.
   - Or if you ever started using numpy, which also has a (different) `numpy.sqrt` function, then you don't want your code to be at the mercy of whichever imports got run, and which order. So then you'd write an explicit `math.sqrt` or `np.sqrt`. (Probably you'd never use `math.sqrt` again, but you get the wider point about avoiding name collisions.)
5. Give the function a **docstring**

   - it's good practice, it tell us the input args and types, and return type(s)
   - you can also mention the input domain is restricted, what assumptions you make, whether you handle corner cases. e.g. *"real coefficients a,b,c, returns real roots only (, errors on negative discriminants)"*
   - particularly important when your code might get thrown over the wall to someone else to use and/or test, i.e. any non-trivial real-world codebase